# Como meter como parametro en una funcion onClick el src de un img

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

usando una api (unsplash) tengo muchas fotos cargadas en la store de redux, y haciendo un map cargo todas con su respectivo button, como conseguiria pasar como parametro a la funcion onCLick del button el src?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<section className="w-full gap-0 sm:columns-2 md:columns-3 xl:columns-4 2xl:columns-5 3xl:columns-6">
        {galery.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <figure key={index} className='relative'>
              <button onClick={() => saveToFavorites(imag.src)} className='absolute left-5 top-3 bg-gray shadow-md'>Guardar</button>
              <img
              className="object-cover p-2"
              src={item.urls.regular}
              onClick={openModal}
              alt={item.alt_description}
            />
            </figure>
          );
        })}
      </section>
```

Esta en la funcion que quiero que envie el src pero no consigo hacer algo asi sencillito

```
const galery = useSelector((state) => state.search);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [imag, setImg] = useState("");

function saveToFavorites(e) {
    setImg(e.target);
    dispatch(actionAddFavorite(imag.src))
    console.log(imag.src)
  }
```

Comment: Has probado `e.target.src`? Todo manejador de evento `onClick`, `onBlur`, `onKeyPress` etc. siempre recibe el evento como argumento. La propiedad `target` de dicho evento es el elemento que disparó el evento. También podrías usar `currentTarget` para mayor precisión. Este objeto contiene los atributos que están establecidos en el mismo, como `src` si se trata de un elemento `<img>`. Saludos

Comment: Pero tengo el disparador lo tiene un botón que está pegado al IMG, usar target afecta al IMG?

Comment: Le podrías poner un `id` a tu imagen, o podrías navegar por el DOM, accedes al padre del botón y luego accedes a la imagen, que será un `sibbling` del botón. Formas hay muchas, pero lo que no puedes hacer es pasarle un argumento al manejador del evento, porque la firma de los manejadores de evento establecen que sólo reciben como argumento el evento. Saludos

Comment: Qué es lo que deseas guardar en `setImg` la url o el objeto como tal? solo necesitas el src en tu función?

Comment: En IMG quiero guardar la URL de la imagen que está con el botón

Comment: Pues que si le doy al botón guarde la URL de la imagen correspondiente, es para guardar favoritos

Answer (score 0):

Pasandole el id del array ya pude comparar los ID luego para identificar la foto

```
<section className="w-full gap-0 sm:columns-2 md:columns-3 xl:columns-4 2xl:columns-5 3xl:columns-6">
        {galery.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <figure key={index} className='relative'>
              <button id={item.id} onClick={() => saveToFavorites(imag.src)} className='absolute left-5 top-3 bg-gray shadow-md'>Guardar</button>
              <img
              className="object-cover p-2"
              src={item.urls.regular}
              onClick={openModal}
              alt={item.alt_description}
            />
            </figure>
          );
        })}
      </section>
```